# JS/ use object which define outside the function

Tags: javascript

I have the next function in JS:

```
function status(){
  this.functionA = function(){}
  //Some others function and fields
}
```

and I have another function:

```
function create(root){
var server = libary(function (port) {
  //Here some functions
});
var returnValue = {
  current:status(),
  cur:function(port){
    current.functionA();
  }}
return returnValue;
}
```

when I call `current.functionA()`, It says that current is undefined. How can I call `functionA()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a function-constructor like `status()`, you'll need to call `new` for it. I've revised part of your code here.

```
var returnValue = {
  current: new status(),
  cur:function(port){
    current.functionA();
  }}
return returnValue;
}
```

Just to differentiate; `create()` doesn't need a `new` statement because you're actually creating and returning an object to refer to, inside of the function.

Comment: I try it as you say, but it still gives me that current is undefined

Comment: @user2450886 Inside `cur`, you need to use `this.current.functionA()` so you refer to the `current` property of `returnValue`. (Assuming you call `cur` as a method of the `returnValue` object, so `this == returnValue`.)

Comment: @apsillers: I use this, but now it gives me the next error: Cannot call method FunctionA() of undefined

Comment: @user2450886 You should edit your question to show a small complete example. Right now, I don't know how and where you're calling `cur`, or even *if* you're calling `cur`.

Comment: @apsillers: I call cur, otherwise it wouldn't give me this exception. I call cur from other function which create this object.

Comment: @user2450886 Here is Katanan314's code plus my `this.current` edit in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FP4U2/ The code runs fine -- if you're using that code and it's failing, whatever is going wrong is in some code you didn't post in your question.

Comment: Thank you, apsillers! I actually did miss that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
function status(){
  this.functionA = function(){alert("functionA");}
}
function create(root){ 
    var returnValue = {
        current:status.call(returnValue), 
        cur:function(port){ this.functionA(); }.bind(returnValue)
    } 
    return returnValue; 
}
create().cur(999);
```

I corrected your issue using the JavaScript "call" and "bind" methods which are part of the Function prototype.